# How do I set video recording rate to 60 fps or 120 fps and change between the two?

Tags: ios, video, iphone

How do I set video recording rate to 60 fps or 120 fps and change between the two? I'm looking to be able to use different FPS rates when recording video with the iPhone 5s.

Answer (score 1):

the only option using the iphone's camera is by switching between Slow-Mo and Video modes. You can then speed up a Slow-Mo video to normal speed in the photos app pretty easily. You can't convert normal videos to Slow-Mo.

There are probably a ton of apps that offer a bit more manual configuration than that. But I don't know of them.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a way to switch between recording frames per second whilst recording, or to record at 60fps at all. Recording with the video mode will record at 30fps and recording with the slow-mo mode will record at 120fps. This 120fps footage can be slowed to 60fps, or simply by removing frames as 30fps footage is recorded, in post processing.